# C++ - Given multiple binary strings, produce binary string where n-th bit is set if in all given strings is n-th bit same

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, uint32

On input I am given multiple `uint32_t` numbers, which are in fact binary strings of length 32. I want to produce binary string ( a.k.a. another `uint32_t` number ) where n-th bit is set to `1` if n-th bit in every given string from input is same.

---

Here is simple example with 4 bit string ( just more simple instance of same problem ) :

**input**: `0011, 0101, 0110`

**output**: `1000`

**because**: first bit is same in every string on input, therfore first bit in output will be set to `1` and 2nd,3rd and 4th will be set to `0` because they have different values.

---

What is the best way to produce output from given input? I know that I need to use bitwise operators but I don't know which of them and in which order.

```
uint32_t getResult( const vector< uint32_t > & data ){
    //todo
}
```

Comment: Remember that binary numbers are like any other numbers when writing them, the first digit is the *right-most* digit. So in your example the *last* digit (and the last bit) is the same in all.

Comment: @Christophe So far I am just trying to understand bitwise operator and I sketch some ideas on paper. I am thinking about using `^` XOR operator and use it somehow with for-each construction in C++ but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am a little bit lost in this LSB and MSB stuff. When writing down 32 bit number, LSB is on the right and MSB on the left, I know that. It is little bit confusing in my original post, I understand

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I doubt it will works. Instead... well, I won't give too much hints to the OP.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 0011 ^ 0101 is 0110 then 0110 ^ 0110 is 0000. Maybe introduce a not to see where the things are similar and where they are dissimilar.  But maybe you have to work with more than just one accumulating variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the bits where all the source bits are 1 and the bits where all the source bits are 0.  Just AND the source values and the NOT of the source values, then OR the results.

```
uint32_t getResult( const vector< uint32_t > & data ){
    uint32_t bitsSet = ~0; 
    uint32_t bitsClear = ~0;
    for (uint32_t d : data) {
        bitsSet &= d;
        bitsClear &= ~d;
    }
    return bitsSet | bitsClear
}
```

Comment: Just the way OPs question / demand is phrased, I figured this was probably a homework assignment.  Nice answer though.

Comment: @JustinRandall it is part of optimalization for brute-force algorithm for calculating edit distance of multiple numbers ( where fixed bits wont change solution ). Is it something wrong when asking for help while working on homework? I didn't ask for solution, but for advice and help with bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to loop over the vector, of course.

Then we can use XOR of the current element and the *next* element. Save the result.

For the next iteration, do the same: XOR of current element with the next element. But then bitwise OR with the saved result of the previous iteration. Save this result. Then continue with this until you have iterated over all (minus one) elements.

The saved result is the complement of the what you want.

---

Taking your example numbers (`0011`, `0101` and `0110`) then the first iteration we have `0011 ^ 0101` which results in `0110`. The next iteration we have `0101 ^ 0110` which results in `0011`. Bitwise OR with the previous result (`0110 | 0011`) gives `0111`. End of loop, and bitwise complement give the result `1000`.

Comment: To see that this is correct, the XOR will be 1 if a bit is different from its successor.  The accumulated OR will be 1 if any value is different from its successor.  Very neat.